# How to prevent local replication of a company database

Tags: replication, lotus-notes, acl, lotus-domino, database-replication

I have a big Lotus Notes company database containing sensitive data and I want to prevent normal users to replicate this database locally.

**Explanation of the main problems :**

1. sensitive data on laptop
2. server deleted documents reappear if the purge interval is more frequent than local replications
3. server deleted documents reappear if users modify them locally

**These solutions are NOT working in my context :**

1. uncheck the "replicate or copy documents" in the ACL for users. If done, users cannot copy/paste content in form fields.
2. check "temporary disable replication" cause the application is replicated accross multiple servers
3. prevent local disk writing

Comment: `prevent local disk writing`? What's this option? It is the first time I see it.

Answer (score 1):

You've ruled out all the features that are designed to help you with this, so you can't prevent local replication. All you can do is track it. There are third party products that can help you do the tracking. One of them is called SecurTrac, by a company called [ExtraComm](https://www.extracomm.com/securtrac). You could write your own tracking, too, using the C API's extension manager routines, or if you don't want to write in C you could ues the [Trigger Happy project on OpenNTF](https://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/Trigger%20Happy), which gives you some boilerplate C code that you can use to trap accesses and which allows you to call Java code to do the rest of the work of actually logging and tracking.

Answer (score 1):

This does not prevent replication, but it prevents opening the database as local replica file. I have created a test database and added this code to postopen event of the database script. Just quick and dirty:

```
Sub Postopen(Source As Notesuidatabase)
  Dim db As NotesDatabase 
  Dim server As String 

  Set db = source.Database
  server = db.Server

  If server = "" Then
      MsgBox "you are not authorized to use this database as local replica file, it will close after click on ok button"
      source.Close
  Else
      'opening allowed, do whatever you want
  End If
End Sub
```