# Why can't I access local copy of Notes DB

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I have a Notes DB on my workspace where the database file location is on a company server and I can access this database because I am member of a group in the ACL.  However, when I make a local copy on my workspace and I attempt to access the database I am given the message "You are not authorised to access that database".  Why is this and how do I resolve the access issue?  I have checked that the "Enforce a consistent Access Control List across all replicas" is checked in the Advanced tab of the ACL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The group you are a member of is unknown in your local names.nsf.

Copy this group document from your company's names.nsf into your local names.nsf
or create it there with the same name and you as a member.

Alternatively, you can copy the database without setting option "Access Control List".
[image]
Then you can set yourself as manager in ACL afterwards. Don't forget to add the original roles too and set finally option "Enforce a consistent Access Control List across all replicas".

(I hope it's not about the database mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45055520/2065611) ;-)

Comment: Thanks Knut.  No my question has nothing to do with the database in the link you added.  I used the second method of creating the copy without the Access Control List because I was not able to find the company's names.nsf file